# How to get a string untill second occurence of "-" and number

Tags: regex, unix

An example: `prod2-03_dl-httpd-prod-8080_access_referer_log.20181111-050000`

I still need value till `prod2-03_dl-httpd-prod`
So basically we need value till second occurrence of '-' and number.

We tried following options:-

```
echo "prod2-03_dl-httpd-prod-8080_access_referer_log.20181111-050000" | sed -r 's/([^-][:digit:]+[^-][:digit:]).*/\1/'
```

Comment: See [my `awk` approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53428572/3832970), it might turn out more robust that `grep` here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `pcregrep` and positive lookahead:

```
$ echo "prod2-03_dl-httpd-prod-8080_access_referer_log.20181111-050000" | 
  grep -Po "^[^-]*-.*?(?=-[0-9])"
prod2-03_dl-httpd-prod
```

Explained some:

- `grep -P`: using PCRE
- `^` from the beginning of the string
- `[^-]*` all non-dashes
- `-` followed by a dash
- `.*?` followed by anything non-greedily
- `(?=-[0-9])` positive lookahead for a dash and a number

Comment: Thanks James, Need one more help - can you please tell how get 8080 from same string.

Comment: Be more specific on the requirement, please. `grep -o 8080 file` otherwise. ;D

Answer (score 0):

It seems the string can be parsed as a delimited string, use `awk`:

```
s="prod2-03_dl-httpd-prod-8080_access_referer_log.20181111-050000"
awk -F'-' '{print $1 "-" $2 "-" $3}' <<< "$s"
# => prod2-03_dl-httpd
awk -F'-' '{sub(/_.*/, "", $5); print $5}' <<< "$s"
# => 8080
awk -F'[-_]' '{print $6}' <<< "$s"
# => 8080
```

See [online `awk` demo](https://ideone.com/bBQR8P)

Here,

- `-F'-'` sets field separator to `-`
- `{print $1 "-" $2 "-" $3}` prints Fields from 1 to 3 with the separator chars in between
- `sub(/_.*/, "", $5)` removes all text beginning with the first `_` in Field 5 and then prints it
- If the number of `-` and `_` is constant before `8080`, `[-_]` separator can be used and then `{print $6}` is enough.